# Is there a way to make geoms fade but persist in gganimate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have geographic data like the following (but a much larger amount of data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

n <- 500

longitude <- runif(n) 
latitude <- runif(n) 
time <- round(runif(n, 0, 100),1) %>% sort
data <- tibble(longitude,latitude) %>% arrange(longitude) %>% mutate(time = time)
```

I can make an animation with gganimate as follows:

```
anim1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group = time)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 10) +
  transition_components(time, exit_length = 30) +
  exit_fade() +
  shadow_mark(color = "red" ,alpha = 0.1, size = 10) 

animate(anim1, nframes = 100)
```

And this gives the following output:

[image]

Here I am using both `exit_fade` for the point to fade away, but also `shadow_mark` with a set alpha in order for the data to persist.  And this is basically very very close to what I want.

The problem is that what's really happening here is that gganimate is putting a `shadow_mark` on immediately after the data point first appears underneath the geom_point, and it then becomes slowly visible while the original point fades. If I just want the point to fade but persist, this is mostly OK (although the fade transition is a little bit weird because the alphas of the original and the `shadow_mark` are adding together visually during the fade). But it becomes a bigger problem because sometimes I need to also resize the point.

If I use a `shadow_mark` that is smaller than the original point, you can see the problem:

```
anim2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group = time)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 10) +
  transition_components(time, exit_length = 30) +
  exit_fade() +
  shadow_mark(color = "red" ,alpha = 0.1, size = 2) 

animate(anim2, nframes = 100)
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

You can see the smaller point appear while the larger point fades out (here I have left out simultaneous resizing for simplicity, but the problem is still present in that case).  So I would like to know if there is a way to do this "properly" in gganimate such that the point actually just fades but persists, without having the `shadow_mark` just drawn underneath and slowly revealed by the fading of the original point?

The reason for the question is that I would ultimately like to smoothly `exit_fade` and `exit_shrink` at the same time such that the final size after the shrink is the same as the smaller size of the `shadow_mark` in the example above and then the point just persists throughout the rest of the animation in the smaller, semi-faded state.

**Note**: I realize that I could `uncount` the data rows and make my own frames and transitions manually within the data and allow the points to persist that way, as has been discussed in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271332/gganimate-plot-where-points-stay-and-line-fades/58347531#58347531).  The problem is my real data set is actually very large, and doing an uncount like this results in a data set that is too big for memory.  So I would prefer a pure gganimate solution if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach duplicates the dataset twice, which does cause the file size to balloon a bit, but probably not as problematic as uncounting would have done. See if it works for you?

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(id = seq(1, n()),               # add an ID column to original dataset, 
         type = "original",         
         size = 10,                      # specify initial size / alpha / any other aspect
         alpha = 1)                      # to be changed during animation

rbind(data,

      data %>%                           # create second version of the dataset, 
        mutate(type = "transiting",      # with time lagged by the desired transition
               time = time + 30,         # amount (30 in the question's example), 
               size = size * 0.2,        # & size / alpha / any other aspect defined
               alpha = alpha * 0.1),     # according to end state after transition;

      data %>%                           # create third version of the dataset, 
        mutate(type = "persisting",      # which should be identical to the second,
               time = max(time) + 30,    # except that the time is set to the max time 
               size = size * 0.2,        # across all rows.
               alpha = alpha * 0.1)) %>%
  
  # pass this combined dataset to ggplot & animate as per normal with explicitly 
  # specified parameters for size / alpha / etc, & group aesthetic set to ID value.
  # no need to specify exit_fade or shadow_mark now, as each point DOESN'T exit at all.
  ggplot(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = id,
             size = size, alpha = alpha)) +
  geom_point(colour = "red") +
  transition_components(time) + 
  ggtitle("{frame_time}") + # optional; added to illustrate frame time explicitly
  scale_size_identity() +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image: animated]